# Find maximum path sum in a grid with three directions

Tags: matrix, dynamic-programming

Given a grid of size M×N,(1≤M,N≤2000) where each cell contains an integer Aij,(|Aij|≤250). We have to find the maximum path from (1, 1) to any cell in the last row. Allowed moves are right, left, and bottom.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvbX8.png)

Please help me to solve this problem.

I tried to use dynamic programming to solve this problem and I found 2 cases to consider, the first one is that we can get to (i, j) from (i-1, j) and from (i, j) we can move left or right such that the sum is > 0, and the another one is that we can get to (i, j) from (i, k) and (i, k) is from (i - 1, k), and then I can move to left or right of (i, k) and right or left of (i, j) but I got Wrong answer.